# Compute the significance of the overlap between 2 or more gene sets

Tags: statistics

I was able to compute the significance of the overlap between 2 gene sets using the cdf function of [scipy hypergeometric distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html).

I wish to be able to perform the same calculation for more than 2 gene sets; should I use the multivariate hypergeometric distribution cdf function for that?

Are there any websites that provides the same calculations over gene sets so I can validate my results?

Comment: Not so trivial, if you want to use a distribution. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52004/overlapping-sets-3-significance-test

Comment: Easiest way is to simulate the data, and see how many times you end up with an intersection set larger than what you see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shot at it, first an example dataset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np
import functools
from matplotlib_venn import venn3
    
# define universe
uni = ["gene"+str(i) for i in range(1000)]
# some overlap
gs1 = uni[250:300] + uni[900:950]
gs2 = uni[:300]
gs3 = uni[250:500]
```

The ever amazing venn diagram:

```
venn3([set(gs1),set(gs2),set(gs3)],set_labels=["gs1","gs2","gs3"])
```

[image]

Then a function to draw a set with length equivalent of each set, randomly from the universe and find length of intersection (all 3):

```
def sim_intersect(uni,set_lengths):
    randomsets = [np.random.choice(uni,n) for n in set_lengths]
    return len(functools.reduce(np.intersect1d,randomsets))
```

We run this 1000 times:

```
permuted_values = [sim_intersect(uni,[len(gs1),len(gs2),len(gs3)]) for i in range(1000)]

plt.hist(permuted_values,bins=range(50))
```

[image]

The probability of observing the starting result, using (B+1)/(M+1) as estimator, see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109207/p-values-equal-to-0-in-permutation-test):

```
(sum(np.array(permuted_values)>obs_n)+1)/(1000+1)
0.000999000999000999
```

Comment: How would a population size parameter fit in this approach? Doesn't the p value should be affected by the total 'available genes' ?

For example,. if I have two gene sets A, B.
 |A| = 250, |B| = 220, |A&B| = 65 As far as I understand,
 the p value should change dramatically if the population size is 300 or 30,000.

Could you please explain where/how does it fit in this approach?

Comment: Yes you are right, the total available genes would matter. In the code above, you would define the set of available genes as ```uni``` . It is not like a hypergeometric where you input a number of genes parameter. You simply simulate the results and see how likely you end up with a result as extreme as yours

Comment: easiest thing to do is to re-run the above simulation with a small "universe"